# Transforming XML to HTML with XSLT

Tags: f#, monads, xslt

I'm still learning from [designing with types non strings](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-non-strings/) by Scott Wlaschin. 
For my project I transform some XML to HTML with xslt. 
Because every filename can have side effects, they are stored in string option types.
If I do the transformation I get an ugly pyramid of `Option.map` and five times more lines of code compared to the simple version.
Is there a shorter way to write that code?

```
open System.Xml.Xsl

type HtmlPage = HtmlPage of string
type XmlFile  = XmlFile of  string
type XslFile  = XslFile of  string


type HtmlTransformer =
    {
        HtmlPage :  HtmlPage    option
        XmlFile :   XmlFile     option
        XslFile :   XslFile     option
    }

let toHtmlNoOption (xmlFn:string) (xsltFn:string) (htmlFn:string) =
    try
        let xslt = new XslCompiledTransform()
        xslt.Load xsltFn
        xslt.Transform (xmlFn,htmlFn)    
    with _-> ()

let toHtml (sc:HtmlTransformer) =
    try
        let xslt = new XslCompiledTransform()
        let xfn = 
            sc.XslFile
            |> Option.map (fun (XslFile xf)  -> xf)
        let xmlFn = 
            sc.XmlFile
            |> Option.map (fun (XmlFile xf)  -> xf)
        let htmlFn = 
            sc.HtmlPage
            |> Option.map (fun (HtmlPage lp)  -> lp)
        xfn
        |> Option.map xslt.Load
        |> Option.map 
            (fun () ->
                htmlFn
                |> Option.map 
                    (fun hFn -> 
                        xmlFn
                        |> Option.map 
                            (fun xFn -> xslt.Transform(xFn,hFn)))
            )
    with 
        _ -> None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because every filename can have side effects, they are stored in string option types.

I don't understand what you mean by that, but it's not particularly important for the rest of the question.

Your concern about the structure of the code is valid. Fortunately, you have several options. Let's start gently.

## Map3

`Option.map` is useful if you have a *single* `option` value, and you want to transform it into another `option` value if the input value is a `Some` case. If you have *two* `option` values, you'll need a hypothetical `Option.map2` function, and in this case, where you have *three* `option` values, you'll need a hypothetical `Option.map3` function. These functions are not yet available in the `Option` module, but [are being considered for inclusion in the future](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1007-additional-Option-module-functions.md).

You can easily write the required function yourself, though:

```
// ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'a option -> 'b option -> 'c option -> 'd option
let optionMap3 f x y z =
    match x, y, z with
    | Some x', Some y', Some z' -> f x' y' z' |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

This completely generic function would enable you to write an `option`-based function adapter over your nice `toHtmlNoOption` function:

```
let toHtml' (sc : HtmlTransformer) =
    let xfn = sc.XslFile |> Option.map (fun (XslFile xf)  -> xf)
    let xmlFn = sc.XmlFile |> Option.map (fun (XmlFile xf)  -> xf)
    let htmlFn = sc.HtmlPage|> Option.map (fun (HtmlPage lp) -> lp)

    (xfn, xmlFn, htmlFn) |||> optionMap3 toHtmlNoOption
```

The return expression uses the exotic `|||>` pipe operator to compose the three `option` values into `toHtmlNoOption`, which will only be invoked if all three values are `Some` cases.

## Computation expression

You can do better, though, using a [computation expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182). There's no built-in computation expression for `option` types, but you can easily add a minimal one that addresses this particular purpose:

```
type OptionBuilder () =
    member this.Bind(v, f) = Option.bind f v
    member this.Return v = Some v

let option = OptionBuilder ()
```

This enables you to rewrite the function like this:

```
let toHtml'' (sc : HtmlTransformer) = option {
    let! XslFile xfn = sc.XslFile 
    let! XmlFile xmlFn = sc.XmlFile
    let! HtmlPage htmlFn = sc.HtmlPage

    return toHtmlNoOption xfn xmlFn htmlFn }
```

Notice how the use of `let!`-bound values enable you to use pattern matching to destructure the string values out of the single-union cases. Within this `option` expression, `xfn`, `xmlFn`, and `htmlFn` all have the type `string`.

Because this expression is evaluated within an `option` computation expression, it'll short-circuit and return `None` as soon as *any* of the `let!`-bound values turn out to be `None`. Only if they are *all* `Some` cases does it evaluate all the way to the end, where it calls into the `toHtmlNoOption` function and returns the return value of that function call.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer that really helped me. So now I will look at [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) to learn more about the exotic operators. 
I started thinking of Computation Expressions after I wrote the code, but I’m still learning them, so your advice helped me.
To be moreprecise: The filenames themselves can not have side effects, but creating and accessing them. Names of missing files are `None` and others are `Some`.